# django-oscar categories and products translations

Tags: django, locale, translation, django-oscar, django-modeltranslation

I want to use `django-oscar` for building an web shop and this shop will provide two main languages.

`Oscar's` translations do very well with regular fields like `View chart` or `Add to chart`, but does not support custom elements e.g. `Categories` or `Product's` `Titles`.

I want have translated:

- `Category`
- `Product.Title`
- `Product.Description`

I've figured out two approaches:

**Approach one** - modify `django-oscar` templates

I can create custom set of tranlsations according to [oscar's translation doc](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.2/topics/translation.html).

And then fill proper `django.po` file with translated categories and product's titles.

Unfortunately I will have to overwrite some templates, because they don't use `trans` templatetag by default. E.g. I would change.

```
<a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{{ category.name }}</a>
```

to

```
<a href="{{ category.get_absolute_url }}">{% trans category.name %}</a>
```

In [this](https://github.com/django-oscar/django-oscar/blob/913da107f1f760a707a0555d06663fc5dbcea4b2/src/oscar/templates/oscar/catalogue/category.html) oscar's template.

Main problem with this approach is need for overwriting templates, updating `django.po` as well as compiling it with every new entry to translate.

**Approach two** - use `django-modeltranslation`

Using [this](https://github.com/deschler/django-modeltranslation) plugin.

**Question**

Does I miss some build in `django-oscar's` feature, or I have to use one of above approaches?

Comment: `django-modeltranslation` solved the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using `django-modeltranslation` was a good idea.

Even updating dashboard according to [customization instructions](http://django-oscar.readthedocs.io/en/releases-1.2/topics/customisation.html) from `oscar's` docs and [ModelForm description](http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/forms.html) from `modeltranslation's` docs done the job well.

Comment: Did you managed solr search for multilanguage descriptions too?

Comment: I'm using `hystack`, but according to this doc page: http://django-modeltranslation.readthedocs.io/en/latest/usage.html#multilingual-manager. I think that it should be working without any modification.